# Llenar varios input con informacion seleccionada de la fila de una tabla que contiene informacion de la base de datos mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql

Necesito seleccionar una la fila de una tabla y que esa fila se muestre en los inputs de un formulario. Esta tabla contiene datos extraidos de mysql, y el llenado de los input solo me funciona con informacion por defecto del HTML ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Esta es mi tabla y las variables que contiene la informacion, he probado varias cosas con javascript y nada me funciona. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el formulario con los input donde necesito mostrar la informacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenida a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código como texto para tratar de reproducir el problema, de otra forma será muy difícil que recibas ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! te será muy útil trabajar con `FormGroup`. Cuando agrupas los campos de un formulario en un `FormGroup`, puedes acceder a la data y visualizar estos valores (como tu quieres) por medio de la propiedad `setValue`. Revisa la documentación de Angular. Te servirá este link: [Reactive Forms - Angular](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)